# What apiGroups and resources exist for RBAC rules in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: xi-{{instanceId}}
  name: deployment-creation
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: ["batch", "extensions"]
  resources: ["jobs"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

In the above example, I permit various operations on pods and jobs.
For pods, the apiGroup is blank. For jobs, the apiGroup may be batch or extensions.
Where can I find all the possible resources, and which apiGroup I should use with each resource?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`kubectl api-resources` will list all the supported resource types and api-group. Here is the table of [resource-types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#resource-types)

Comment: The linked document specifies the `apiGroup` column in the place where `kubectl api-resources` specifies the `apiVersion` column and they differ, which is confusing. Anyway able to disspell?

Comment: former comment addressed in https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/35206

Answer (score 2):

just to add to @suresh's answer, here is a [list of apiGroups](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/#-strong-api-groups-strong-)